# anyway to tell if a user has app installed using facebook?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to know if a user has a app installed dy using Facebook? 
I was thinking there may be a way because it asks for permissions from the user, so I'm sure its something that registers. 
I want to be able to tell a user if any friends on Facebooka particular app installed that uses Facebook. If so tell them who.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE is_app_user  AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

I can see an Android Tag. Try this [Android Application (component)](http://codecanyon.net/item/android-startup-application-/243698)

Saved me a week of questioning how to make Facebook, android application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to post something to their wall through your application after authorization, YES. With the proper privileges, I suppose you could then query their friends feeds to see who else has a similar post on their wall. This may not be a very reliable method though if it works because people can just delete, and often do delete their posts from apps. See these links to help you with this.

Authentication - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Mobile Apps - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

**edit: nice answer regarding the FQL queries, use that.**